# CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue function always returning -1

Tags: objective-c, macos, java-native-interface

I am find the index a CGWindowID from the CFArrayRef. This is my code.

```
CFArrayRef window2ids =CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly ,kCGNullWindowID);
jint windowid = 440; // I have selected this id from the CFArrayRef and trying to find the index
CFRange range = {0, CFArrayGetCount(window2ids)};
const void *p;
p = &windowid;
CFIndex index = CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue(window2ids, range, p);
return index;
```

But the above code is always returning `-1`. Which means the window id is not present in the CFArrayRef. How is that possible if I am selecting the window id from that array? How to solve my issue?

Comment: (lldb) p/x 440
(int) $10 = 0x000001b8 How did you get magic number 440? Is is static a present always. If not this might be the cause why it's not there

Comment: I am not sure about number 440 or 446. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Code is ok, the number is not present in the array (not for me). How do you know it's there? Where did you get 440/446. Is it in documentation?

Comment: It is an application created by me. I have retrieved the window Id from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo using title and owner name.